# Identifier expected?

Tags: java, symbols, identifier

Given the following code:

```
public class Test1 {
    int i;
    i = 4;
}   

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 t1 = new Test1();
        System.out.println(t1.i);
    }
}
```

why do I get the following when I try to compile Test2?

```
./Test1.java:3: error: <identifier> expected
    i = 4;
     ^
./Test1.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    i = 4;
    ^
  symbol:   class i
  location: class Test1
2 errors
```

Comment: You cannot run arbitrary lines of code outside of a method.  Move `i=4;` into a method or initializer block.

Comment: Because that's bad syntax. Either initialize `i` directly with `int i = 4;` or move the `i = 4;` to a method or constructor, that's where code can be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign variables in the class body.  Try this instead:

```
public class Test1 {
    int i;
    {
        i = 4;
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could assign `i` in the constructor, or in a setter method:

```
public class Test1 {
    int i;

    public Test1(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring "int i" inside class. Either u can assign along with declaration or use getter and setter.

```
public class Test1 {
    int i = 4;
}
```

OR

```
public class Test1 {
    private int i = 4;

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```